# Printing methods in Class library C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a generic Printing class in my class library, just like I would create a generic DataAccess class to access data and return data to models;
however, what I was able to find on the internet, usually needs a FlowDocument and a printdialog; but these seem to be residing in presentation and  WindowBase; These do not seem like the DLL's I am going to need in my Classlibrary (?)

I am new to classlibraries, and I would like to use them to contain as much logic as I need to have one DLL for multiple interfaces, would this still be the way to go, or do I need to create a printing class per GUI type (ASP, and WPF for now) ?

Comment: You can get the Methods info as `typeof(T).GetMethods()` which will return the array of MehodInfo `MethodInfo[]`

Comment: WPF is very different to ASP/Web printing.  You might be able to have a similar interface, but I think that would be very limiting.  If it was me, anything I wanted to print, I'd create a PDF, and then 'open' that.  That would then work with local (WPF) and remote (web) documents.

Comment: Thank you; that confirms my "class per GUI" theory